# Install ends prematurely with error "must be launched with administrative privileges."

Tags: wix

I'm using Wix to create an installer to deploy a simple .NET 6 web API in IIS. When I launch the .msi it displays an error popup with the message "The [application] must be launched with administrative privileges." The only option is to click OK which advances the installer to the "Setup Wizard ended prematurely" page.

Since it's an .msi there's no Run as Administrator right-click menu option, though I can install my application from an Administrator command prompt. Is there a property I can set so that the installer either doesn't require administrator privileges or automatically executes with administrator privileges?

Answer (score 0):

You can run it as administrator [using comand prompt](https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-run-msi-file-as-administrator-from-command-prompt-in-windows/).

Or try this attributes for you package

```
 <Package InstallPrivileges="elevated" InstallScope="perMachine">
```

Comment: `AdminImage` isn't related to elevation.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Just wrote how it worked for me before, but now, after your comment and some search got that I was wrong. Thanks